# localStorage same index name in another app

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage

Im' developing an app with ionic/cordova and have used the `localStorage` for many times.
For example I have such a thing:

```
window.localStorage['is_user_paid'] = 1;
```

So, if user pay the money, I set this `localStorage` item.

Now, if **another app** set this  to 1, and run in the device, does my app assume the user is really paid?  Is it necessary to use an app key like `2afjx8y_is_user_paid` ? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running under Cordova, `localStorage` is sandboxed to your app; no other apps can see the content within your app's `localStorage`, nor can they change the contents. Likewise, your app can only see its own `localStorage` contents.

Now, sandboxed does not mean not readable/editable by the user, however, which is why it is vitally important not to store things like passwords in `localStorage` -- the file itself is mostly human-readable and easily accessible by your end user. However, *apps* are prevented from accessing any `localStorage` other than their own.

> *Note*: there are ways around this when apps from the same company need to share data, but they involve a different storage mechanism.)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this once upon a time by creating a unique identifier within my app (stored not in the code but in the datastore), and I would use it whenever accessing local storage.

The code is predictable enough, the logic is what's important:

- Create a value in your datastore (or a file that isn't readable via a URL, like in the GAE that might be an app.yaml file, or whatever) that you use as unique ID. You can do this by hand if you have to. Generate a GUID of some kind and just store it. Don't put it in your dev code or hardcode it into a JS page, make sure it's off to the side (unless you don't care, but you probably should).
- Whenever you access local storage, either to get or put, run it through a function that retrieves that info (or already retrieved it as part of bootstrapping the app, whatever works for your context), and just prepend it to whatever you're calling your key.

That way you can continue coding as if you're just using an easy to understand key, like 'user_name', but the stored/retrieved key will look like "abd12342Baa345324w3423sdfs323DD_user_name".

From time to time, if so inclined, you can change that key, set up your code such that if it retrieves 'user_name' with the old key, you swap it out for the new one and continue your ops as usual.

I did this at work for an app in production and all around it was considered a legit way to go about it. I got the approach from a GAE article that shows how to store and retrieve client tokens for Google Login without putting them in your code; you can even store different versions of that UID for dev/qa/prod and whatever else. It's not specific to GAE, the concept should pan out to any environment.

Of course, if another developer on that project decides to use that same function and same GUID, then the problem just moves. A little discipline can clean that up though, I put in a comment above that util function and we never have a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. But @Kerri's answer is more proper for cordova. You are right when working in a browser (web app). Finally I tested in a real device, and I alerted the same `localStorage` index. It alerted `undefined`